How to save the output from using Jupyter Notebook's Python packages tabulate and IPython.display packages
I have the following code that prints some nice tables in a cell of Jupyter Notebook. However, I also want to also export it to a png or pdf file. How am I going to accomplish this?
from tabulate import tabulate
from IPython.display import Latex, display

def display_table(summary, data, best_formula, worst_formula):
    print(f"\n{summary}\n")
    print(tabulate(data, headers='keys', tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
    print(f"\nBest Results Formula:")
    display(Latex(f'${best_formula}$'))
    print(f"\nWorst Results Formula:")
    display(Latex(f'${worst_formula}$'))
    print("\n" + "-" * 80 + "\n")

# Mock data and formulas
summary = "Comparison of Different Algorithms"
data = [
    {"Algorithm": "A", "Accuracy": 0.95, "Precision": 0.93, "Recall": 0.92},
    {"Algorithm": "B", "Accuracy": 0.88, "Precision": 0.85, "Recall": 0.84},
    {"Algorithm": "C", "Accuracy": 0.80, "Precision": 0.78, "Recall": 0.76}
]
best_formula = r'\text{Accuracy} = \frac{TP + TN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}'
worst_formula = r'\text{Error Rate} = \frac{FP + FN}{TP + TN + FP + FN}'

# Display the table and formulas
display_table(summary, data, best_formula, worst_formula)


How about display(tabulate(data, headers='keys', tablefmt='html')), then download notebook as pdf / print webpage as pdf?

Did you try to use  matplotlib:

pip install matplotlib tabulate
save result as png


This is a duplicate, there are 129 hits for jupyter save PNG, please identify which one is a good target.
